# Tables next to each other with diagonal separating of a cell

Tags: tikz-pgf, tables, positioning, minipage

I have a question concerning the positioning of tables next to each in Latex. I found a solution, but however, I also want a diagonal in one cell, which is why I need the tikz-envornment, then again, the fitting doesn't really look good (centering, distance etc.) Can anyone give me advice on how to align the tables in a more pretty way?

[image: with the table environment]

[image: with the tikz- environment]

```
\begin{document}
\usepackage{table}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, fit}
\begin{table}[]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{ll|c|c|l}
\cline{3-4}&    & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{true categories}   &  \\  \cline{3-4}
&   & 1 & 0  &                          \\   \cline{1-4}
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\parbox[t]{4mm}{\multirow{2}{*}{\rotatebox[]{90}{\centering predicted}}}}
 & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{1} & True Positive                                                            & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}False Positive\\ (Type I error)\end{tabular} &  \\ \cline{2-4}
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{}                                      & \multicolumn{1}{c|
{0} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}False Negative\\ (Type II error)\end{tabular} & True Negative                                                           &  \\ \cline{1-4}
\end{tabular}
\caption{The confusion matrix for predicted and true categories.}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

And the second one is:

```
\begin{table}[!htb] \centering
\begin{subtable}
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=1.5cm,y=0.5cm]
    \draw (0,0) grid [step=1] (3,3);
    \node at (1.5,2.5) {\textbf{1}};
    \node at (2.5,2.5) {\textbf{0}};

    \node at (0.5,1.5) {\textbf{1}};
    \node at (0.5,0.5) {\textbf{0}};  
    \node at (1.5,1.5) {331};
    \node at (2.5,1.5) {25}; 
    \node at (1.5,0.5) {0};
    \node at (2.5,0.5) {350};
    \draw (0,3) -- (1,2);
    \node at (1.0,3.0) [below left,inner sep=1pt] {\small$\textbf{t}$};
    \node at (0.0,2.0) [above right,inner sep=1pt] {\small$\textbf{p}$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{subtable} \begin{subtable}
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=1.5cm,y=0.5cm]
    \draw (0,0) grid [step=1] (3,3);
    \node at (1.5,2.5) {\textbf{1}};
    \node at (2.5,2.5) {\textbf{0}};  
    \node at (0.5,1.5) {\textbf{1}};
    \node at (0.5,0.5) {\textbf{0}};    
    \node at (1.5,1.5) {331};
    \node at (2.5,1.5) {25};  
    \node at (1.5,0.5) {0};
    \node at (2.5,0.5) {350};
    \draw (0,3) -- (1,2);
    \node at (1.0,3.0) [below left,inner sep=1pt] {\small$\textbf{t}$};
    \node at (0.0,2.0) [above right,inner sep=1pt] {\small$\textbf{p}$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{subtable}
\caption{The confusion matrices for the estimates are given. The left table shows the estimates applied to the training set with an accuracy of $0.964$. The table on the right hand side shows the estimates applied on the test set with an accuracy of $0.966$.}
\end{table}
```

Comment: I doin't think you need a sledgehammer to crack a nut: you should take a look at the `diagbox` package, which is dedicated to this special problem.

Comment: @Bernhard! Thank you! I think that was what I was looking for!

Answer (score 2):

I just wanted to share my solution with others maybe seeking for a similar approach.

[image: table]

```
\begin{table}[!htb]
        \begin{minipage}{0.4\textwidth}
          \centering
            \begin{tabular}{|c| c | c |}
        \hline
        \diagbox{\textbf{\footnotesize{Pred.}}}{\textbf{\footnotesize{True}}}
                                 & \mathbf{$1$}     & \textbf{$0$}   \\ \hline
        \textbf{$1$}        & $331$ & $25$  \\  \hline
        \textbf{$0$}        & $0$   & $350$ \\  \hline
        \end{tabular}
        \end{minipage}  \begin{minipage}{0.4\textwidth}
          \centering
            \begin{tabular}{|c| c | c |}
        \hline
        \diagbox{\textbf{\footnotesize{Pred.}}}{\textbf{\footnotesize{True}}}
                             & $1$  & $0$    \\ \hline
        $1$     & $153$ & $11$  \\ \hline
        $0$     & $0$   & $150$ \\  \hline
        \end{tabular}
        \end{minipage} 
        \caption{}
    \end{table}
```

Answer (score 0):

For the first table (to much color, but you can change or delete them) you can try this.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{colortbl}  % Für farbige Tabellen
\usepackage{ragged2e}  % Für besseres links-, rechtsbündig
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{hhline}

\definecolor{Cts1}{HTML}{5B86C9}
\definecolor{Cts2}{HTML}{4C84DC}
\definecolor{Cts3}{HTML}{0947A9}
\definecolor{Cts4}{HTML}{032357}
\definecolor{Cts5}{HTML}{626FCE}
\definecolor{Cts6}{HTML}{54A2C4}
\definecolor{Cts7}{HTML}{43ACD9}
\definecolor{Cts8}{HTML}{0472A1}
\definecolor{Cts9}{HTML}{02364C}
\definecolor{Cts10}{HTML}{013B53}
\definecolor{Cts11}{HTML}{040E5B}

\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\hspace{0pt}\Centering}p{#1}}
\newcommand{\mcc}[2]{\multicolumn{#1}{!{\vlineTS}c!{\vlineTS}}{#2}}
\newcommand{\mccc}[3]{\multicolumn{#1}{!{\vlineTS}>{\cellcolor{Cts#2}}c!{\vlineTS}}{#3}}

\begin{document}

\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.8}
\newcommand{\vlineTS}[1][1.2pt]{\color{gray!70}\vrule width #1}
\setlength\arrayrulewidth{1.2pt}\arrayrulecolor{gray!70}%
\begin{tabular}[t]{|C{4.4cm}|C{3.5cm}|C{4.15cm}|C{4.15cm}|}\hhline{*{4}{|-}}
    \mcc{2}{\cellcolor{Cts1}}   & \multicolumn{2}{!{}>{\cellcolor{Cts2}}c!{\vlineTS}}{\color{white}Zustand der Wirklichkeit} \\\hhline{*{2}{|>{\arrayrulecolor{Cts1}}-}>{\arrayrulecolor{gray!70}}*{2}{|-}}
     \mccc{2}{1}{\multirow{-2}*{\color{white}Fehler beim Testen von Hypothesen}}   & \cellcolor{Cts3}\color{white}$H_{0}$ ist wahr & \cellcolor{Cts6}\color{white}\color{white}$H_{0}$ ist falsch \\\hhline{*{4}{|-}}
     \multicolumn{1}{!{\vlineTS}>{\cellcolor{Cts7}}c!{}}{\multirow{2}*{\cellcolor{Cts7}}} & \mccc{1}{8}{\color{white}abgelehnt}  &
     \multicolumn{1}{!{}>{\cellcolor{Cts11!70}}c!{\vlineTS}}{\color{white}Fehler 1. Art} & \multicolumn{1}{!{}>{\cellcolor{Cts11}}c!{\vlineTS}}{\color{white}Richtige Entscheidung} \\\hhline{*{1}{|>{\arrayrulecolor{Cts7}}-}>{\arrayrulecolor{gray!70}}*{3}{-}}
     \multicolumn{1}{!{\vlineTS}>{\cellcolor{Cts7}}c!{}}{\raisebox{0.52cm}[0.52cm]{\color{white}Nullhypothese $H_{0}$ wird}}   &
     \mccc{1}{7}{\color{white}nicht abgelehnt}   &
     \multicolumn{1}{!{}>{\cellcolor{Cts9}}c!{\vlineTS}}{\color{white}Richtige Entscheidung}  & \multicolumn{1}{!{}>{\cellcolor{Cts10!80}}c!{\vlineTS}}{\color{white}Fehler 2. Art} \\\hhline{*{4}{|-}}
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```